# Laravel resource conditional return

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

I've got simple laravel resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'unread' => $this->unread,
            'details' => new EmployeeAddressResource($this->employeeAddress),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is working fine, now I want to make details conditional :

```
       'details' => $this
        ->when((auth()->user()->role == 'company'), function () {
               return new EmployeeAddressResource($this->employeeAddress);
                }),
```

and it works fine too, but how can I add other condition to return other resource? For exaple, if role is `user` i want to get resource: `CompanyAddressResource`

I tried this:

```
       'details' => $this
        ->when((auth()->user()->role == 'company'), function () {
                    return new EmployeeAddressResource($this->employeeAddress);
                })
        ->when((auth()->user()->role == 'user'), function () {
                    return new CompanyAddressResource($this->companyAddress);
                }),
```

but this is not working, when I'm logged as `company` it gives no `details`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $arrayData = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'unread' => $this->unread
    ];

    if(auth()->user()->role == 'company'){
        $arrayData['details'] = new EmployeeAddressResource($this->employeeAddress);
    }else {
        $arrayData['details'] = new CompanyAddressResource($this->companyAddress);

    }

    return $arrayData
}
```

Comment: thank you for this example, very helpful and not so obvious